# App Script run basic queries using Cloud SQL

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I am looking how to create basic queries from Cloud SQL using App Script.

```
q1: "SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = 'some name';"
q2: "UPDATE users SET name = 'other name' WHERE id = 1;"
q3: "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 1;"
```

I can read the entire table and insert data, however i cannot find the documentation on the google docs site for these types of queries.

I have tried using the query filter however it returns a bool not the ID INT, I am looking for.

```
var id =app.datasources.Users.query.filters.name._equals == "some name";
app.Pages.Page1.decendents.label1.text = id;
:>> Type mismatch: Cannot set type Boolean for property text. Type String is expected
```

Note: Users table sql equivelent (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(64), PRIMARY KEY(id))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query server script syntax is wrong. Try

```
var query =  app.models.Users.newQuery(); //new query
query.filters.name._equals = "some name"; //Note single`=`; 
var records = query.run(); //run the query
app.Pages.Page1.decendents.label1.text = records[0].id;
```

#### To Read:

- [Query#run](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#Query)

Comment: app.datasources.Users.newQuery is not a function. Am i missing something here ? there is Users.query.filter but no Users.newQuery()

Comment: models also has no function newQuery. the closes material i can find is https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_datasources however it does not describe how to retun the actual data.

Comment: @scott  Is there no `app.models.Users.newQuery()`? This https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#Query says there is.

Comment: no, it has datasources, fields and relations as options. The closes thing is Users.query which looks to be the same as newQuery() but does not have the run() option.

Comment: yes custome cloud sql. the top option when clicking DATA +.

Comment: @Scott Can you try it in server side scripting?

Comment: Thank you. it Works server side. looks like I'm going to have to deal with async requests again though,

Comment: @scott Great. But I believe this can also be done client side.

Comment: @scott try `var ds = app.datasources.Users; ds.query.filters.name._equals = "some name";ds.load()`. This limits the current data to just this filter. The text needed should already be  bound to `@datasource.item.id`

Comment: just returns the first id (1) despite the input. console.log(ds.item.Id);